# How to implement AngularJS app in Laravel Blade

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I need implement this: https://github.com/pshevtsov/flashcards into my Laravel Blade View. I tried to install angular and link all files in blade file. but it doesn't work, because laravel and angular use `{{ }}` in files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set custom AngularJS curly braces to prevent conflict with Blade template engine:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []) 

  .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    // To prevent the conflict of `{{` and `}}` symbols
    // between Blade template engine and AngularJS templating we need
    // to use different symbols for AngularJS.

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%=');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
  });
```

I suggest to use `<%= %>` because it's the often used construction, you can find it in [Underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/).

After that Angular code will look like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
    <p><%= phone.name %></p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 7):

In Laravel 5 you can tell Blade to ignore curly braces by doing

```
@{{ $name }}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Jan 2016 one needs to do only this:

- download `app.js` from Angular homepage.
- find

`function $InterpolateProvider() {
    var startSymbol = '{{';
    var endSymbol = '}}';`

and chenge them into whatever, I guess an unofficial practice is <% %>
`function $InterpolateProvider() {
    var startSymbol = '<%';
    var endSymbol = '%>';`

The credit should go to 
https://scotch.io/quick-tips/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

In blade template I code like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="item" ng-cloak><?='{{item.name}}'?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.3 version introduced a new command to mark the block “as-is”, without parsing:

```
@verbatim
        Hello, {{ name }}.
@endverbatim
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste from https://www.trioangle.com/blog/how-to-use-angularjs-in-laravel-blade/

**Method 1: Change AngularJS Tags**

```js
var sampleApp = angular.module(‘app’, [], function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol(‘<%’);
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(‘%>’);
});
```

Now Laravel will use the {{ variableName }} and Angular will use <% variableName %>. Just like that, you can use Laravel Blade and Angular. You can also change this to anything your heart desires.

**Method 2: Change Laravel Tags**

```js
Blade::setContentTags(‘<%’, ‘%>’); // for variables and all things Blade
Blade::setEscapedContentTags(‘<%%’, ‘%%>’); // for escaped data
```

Variables will be: <% $variable %>. Comments will be: <%– $variable –%>. Escaped data will look like: <%% $variable %%>. You can also change this to anything your heart desires.

**Method 3: Without changing any Tags**

```js
@{{ variableName }}
```

Now Laravel will use the {{ variableName }} and Angular will use @{{ variableName }}.

I’ve explained you all the methods of AngularJS usage in Laravel Blade and You are recommended to use **Method 3**.